# Varying amount of iterations in XSL recursive loop within a for loop

Tags: templates, xslt, for-loop, recursion

I'm generating a CSV file from an XML using XSL. The XML contains Main elements with child elements Tags, which in turn contain varying amounts of child elements Tag. A part of the XML looks for example like this:

```
<Main>
    <Tags>
        <Tag>tag1</Tag>
        <Tag>tag2</Tag>
        <Tag>tag3</Tag>
    </Tags>
</Main>
<Main>
    <Tags>
        <Tag>tag1</Tag>
        <Tag>tag2</Tag>
        <Tag>tag3</Tag>
        <Tag>tag4</Tag>
        <Tag>tag5</Tag>
        <Tag>tag6</Tag>
    </Tags>
</Main>
```

In the XSL I have a for each loop that goes through all my Main elements of my XML file.  I want to print the values for all the Tag elements. I do this in another for-each loop which is inside the major loop. However, **I always want to iterate 10 times, regardless of the amount of Tag elements**. I want to print some text in each of the remaining iterations when I have exceeded the amount of printable Tag.

This is the output I'm after:

```
tag1,tag2,tag3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4,tag5,tag6,1,1,1,1,
```

After the Tag for each loop, I'm calling a template, providing a variable with the amount of Tag in Tags. I then want the template to call itself recursively until it has done the varying amount of remaining iterations for the Tag elements of the current Main element. The amount of Tag elements changes with each Main iteration, which I suspect is a problem in my current solution (which causes my transformation software, Notepad++ with XML Tools, to crash):

```
<xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:for-each select="Main">
        <xsl:for-each select="Tags/Tag">
            <xsl:value-of select="Tag"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:call-template name="repeatable">
            <xsl:with-param name="tagamount" select="count(Tags/*)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>

        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="repeatable">

    <xsl:param name="tagamount"/>
    <xsl:param name="index" select="0" />

    <xsl:text>1,</xsl:text>

    <xsl:if test="not($index = 10-$tagamount)">
        <xsl:call-template name="repeatable">
            <xsl:with-param name="index" select="$index + 1" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>
```

Does anyone have any idea if it's possible to do this type of varying iteration, or am I out of luck?

Edit:

I managed to solve it. The problem was I had forgotten to pass on the variable tagamount with each recursive call. See my solution further below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

This XSLT stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Sets the number of iterations per Tags element. -->
  <xsl:variable name="maximum" select="10"/>

  <!-- Matches all the Tags elements and calls a recursive template, intializing the count to 1. -->
  <xsl:template match="//Tags">
    <xsl:call-template name="output-tags">
      <xsl:with-param name="count" select="1"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- A recursive template that will repeat itself until its count reaches the maximum value. 
       If the count is equal to or less then the number of Tag elements inside the current Tags
       element, then find the Tag element in the count position and print its value. Otherwise,
       print 1. -->
  <xsl:template name="output-tags">
    <xsl:param name="count"/>

    <xsl:if test="$count &lt;= $maximum">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$count &lt;= count(Tag)">
          <xsl:value-of select="Tag[count(preceding-sibling::Tag) = $count - 1]"/>
          <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:text>1,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>

      <xsl:call-template name="output-tags">
        <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count + 1"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces the following output when applied to your example input XML:

```
tag1,tag2,tag3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4,tag5,tag6,1,1,1,1,
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's interesting to see the different ways we solved it. Although both solve the problem, I'll mark this one as the solution since it matches the outlaid structure the most - as a recursive loop that can be used within a for loop (the Main element loop).

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't wrap my head around your code. How about something simpler?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:variable name="sep" select="','"/>
<xsl:variable name="LF" select="'&#10;'"/>
<xsl:variable name="filler" select="'1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10'"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="rt/Main/Tags">
    <xsl:for-each select="Tag">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(., $sep)"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
<xsl:value-of select="substring($filler, 2*count(Tag)+1)"/> 
<xsl:value-of select="$LF"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note:
1. Your XML is missing a root element: I am using "rt" as a placeholder.
2. For testing purposes, I have changed "1,1,1,..." into "1,2.3...".

Comment: +1, the only edge case is that you'll get a trailing comma if there are in fact ten or more `Tags` elements.

Comment: The required output shows a trailing comma at each line - so I guess I am actually _missing_ a trailing comma in the filler. Anyway, it should be easy to adjust in either direction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I wasn't clear enough in that the Main for loop needs to be separate from the Tags loop since there are also other elements in addition to the Tags that need to be printed, under Main, but that I omitted for more readability. With minor modifications, however, your solution worked! I changed the outer loop to "rt/Main" (I do have a root element, just omitted it too) and the inner for loop to "Tags/Tag".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers!

I managed to solve it right after I posted. The problem was I had forgotten to send the tagamount variable with the recursive call. After adding it, it works. The repeatable template then looks like this:

```
<xsl:param name="tagamount"/>
<xsl:param name="index" select="0" />

<xsl:text>1,</xsl:text>

<xsl:if test="not($index = 10-$tagamount)">
    <xsl:call-template name="repeatable">
        <xsl:with-param name="tagamount" select="$tagamount"/> <-----------
        <xsl:with-param name="index" select="$index + 1" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
```